# RoutingEffect ignored in Release

Tags: uwp, xamarin.forms, xamarin.uwp

I've created a `RoutingEffect` in my PCL and matching `PlatformEffect` in my UWP project.  I am adding the `RoutingEffect` to the `Effects` collection in the constructor of my custom control which derives from `ContentView`.

This all works great when the application is run in Debug.  If I switch to Release then the effect does not get attached.  If I add a breakpoint to the contructor of my `RoutingEffect` then I get a message:

*The breakpoint will not currently be hit. No executable code of the debugger's target code type is associated with this line. Possible causes include: conditional compilation, compiler optimizations, or the target architecture of this line is not supported by the current debugger code type.*

If I untick "Optimize code" in the project properties for all projects then the constructor for the `RoutingEffect` does get hit, however `OnAttached` in the `PlatformEffect` still doesn't get hit.

Why is there this difference in behaviour and how do I get it to work correctly when built in Release?

Comment: I think these are two different issues. When you create a Release build, Debug symbols are not supplied so that is why no breakpoints will be hit. If you want to be sure, try to create an alert or something other obvious to be sure the `OnAttached` gets hit on a Release build.

Comment: This isn't correct - other breakpoints within both projects are hit even on a Release build.

Comment: Ok, did you clean and rebuild? Make sure you have the latest code in your release build?

Comment: Many times, I've also confirmed the behaviour is the same on both Desktop and Phone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assemblies containing PlatformEffects need to be explicitly specified within the `Forms.Init` overload within the UWP project, as detailed at:

https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/83507/uwp-platformeffect-does-not-get-attached-when-in-release-build#latest

https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/platform-features/windows/installation/universal/#Troubleshooting